# How do I make Firefox forget HTTP Basic Auth?

Tags: firefox, http

How can I make Firefox "invalidate" it's saved HTTP Basic Auth credentials for a website from the client side?

Currently, I have to restart the browser, which is rather cumbersome with multiple tabs open.

Is there a way to do this without having to restart Firefox/clear the cache/etc.

Answer (score 107):

You can choose **Clear Recent History** from the **History** menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>, Macs: <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>). You can then select to just clear **Active Logins** from the details to just clear those sessions.

In older versions of Firefox (such as FF3), **Clear Recent History** is under the **Tools** menu. The shortcut is the same.

Comment: In the current Firefox, this menu option is in the `History` menu, not `Tools`. I verified this with Firefox 29.0.1.

Comment: works on firefox thanx

Answer (score 97):

If you change username and password from the original session to one which will not authenticate, Firefox will destroy all reference to the old authentication and attempt the new one.

You can change/set authentication by adding user:pass@ to the beginning of the URL, example:
http://user:pass@www.example.com/

If you are logged into www.example.com with user:pass then typing (adding to the beginning of the address) anything@ will cause this to happen, example:
http://abc@www.example.com/

A fast fix which doesn't require any plugins.

Please note this only works for HTTP Basic Auth.

An additional side benefit is this will affect only the website you are interacting with. All other logins to any other website will remain active.

Comment: This is an awesome answer.  Simple, easy-to-use, no additional software required, and clever in a non-obviously obvious sort of way.

Comment: On a side note, this should work with most other browsers also, including Chrome and Internet Explorer (IE)

Comment: @DrewAnderson last time I checked, only firefox supported the user:pass@ notation in the url bar.

Comment: My current Apache2 configuration just cuts away basic-auth part in URL, so I had to fallback to "official" way by heavyd above.

Comment: I use the slightly shorter version http://user@www.example.com/ , an empty password works just as well.

Answer (score 12):

The [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) toolbar allows HTTP authentication to be reset within a browser session.

From Firefox's Context Menu, choose Web Developer -> Miscellaneous -> Clear Private Data -> HTTP Authentication.

Comment: Can't find this on current Firefox

Comment: Unfortunately, that feature seems to have disappeared at some point since I posted this answer.

Comment: Just tested it, works! Please note: that's not part of Firefox's bundled dev tools, you have to install the linked add-on.

Answer (score 6):

Make the request from a private window.

In Firefox: `File - New Private Window` (Ubuntu `Ctrl+Shift+P`)
In Chrome `New incognito Window` (Ubuntu `Ctrl+Shift+N`)

Answer (score 3):

> there is no way for the website to offer a log out option

This is wrong.
There are several and simple ways for the website to offer a logout options.

1) Logout link will point to a URL on the same domain containing credentials that are intentionally incorrect

2) Logout link will trigger javascript with following code snippet (Microsoft Internet Explorer only):

```
<script>document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false');</script>
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a way to reliably invalidates credentials that behaves consistently across browses and doesn't pop up an unwanted login box.

Comment: Logout link using incorrect credentials is already covered in [another answer](http://superuser.com/a/458577/427799)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help anyone else, but in my case i thought that it was a bad password that firefox was storing when i couldn't access a site with basic HTTP authentication.  But it turns out that site was actually using NTLMv1 (windows version of basic http authentication) which firefox has now disabled by default since version 30.

To enable go to about:config, and set the pref network.negotiate-auth.allow-insecure-ntlm-v1 to True.

[Firefox does not prompt for password for http authenticated sites, how to make it prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/770897/firefox-does-not-prompt-for-password-for-http-authenticated-sites-how-to-make-i)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove login information, including the httpswd authentication requested by Apache, from any single site you want, without having to delete the entire history or login information from all sites:

Firefox: Burger icon (Options) at the top right under `X` -> `Preferences` -> `Privacy & Security` -> `Logins and Passwords` section -> `Saved logins` button -> Select from the list the page from which you want to delete login data -> Press the `Delete` button at the top right

A similar question is here: [Firefox not deleting HTTP Basic authentication credentials although being instructed to do so](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/192828/firefox-not-deleting-http-basic-authentication-credentials-although-being-instru)

Answer (score -2):

Well, I expire the client's PHPSESSIONID.  When you expire it, it will remove it from the client browser. The second step (which I haven't figured out) would be to delete the session cookie on the server side that would remove the auth state on the server before it times out and will prevent the server from generating a new phpsessionid when it see this client without the cookie.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.cookie = "PHPSESSID=;Path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;";     
    </script>
```

Comment: An HTTP basic authentication does not imply a session in the server, neither a cookie. Also, even if it did, your solution would not work in almost any case since nowadays almost all session cookies are marked as `secure` which forbids javascript to access them.

Comment: well it takes a cookie out of firefox browser when I look at the cookies, but there is more to it. when I clear the bowser cache and delete active logins, then when I go back to the directory on the website I get the http auth dialog box. I wonder if there is a global command that will flush its active login from the browser. If not, there should be.

Comment: My bad, I meant "http-only" flag which forbids javascript to access the data inside the cookie programmatically. As for the original question itself, I stumbled upon a way which would make some browsers forget, but in some cases (like in IE) they have rendered it unusable for security reasons: if you type the url prefixed by a nonexistent user and password, they would "overwrite" your previous login: https://logoff:nopasswd@www.site.com

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way is to **log out** from the site instead of just closing the tab. If this is not an option and you know before hand you will be visiting a site you want forgotten you can install [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) and run your Firefox (or any browser) in a sandbox. Delete the contents of the sandbox when done and everything you have done is gone.

Comment: [HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is a special type of HTTP header that causes your web browser to prompt you for a user name and password, then re-send it automatically when it's needed. When a website uses this type of authentication, there is **no way for the website to offer a log out option**. In most browsers, you have to close the browser for it to forget your login information.

Comment: @Bavi_H: I've heard that some browsers will forget existing sessions if the site sends a HTTP 401 while logged in.

Comment: Just clearing site cookies do not invalidate saved username and password for basic authentication.